# How to color MySQL data in PHP, based on certain conditions like marks obtained and categorizing them based on legend?

Tags: php, mysql, tags

Please be lenient on me as I am yet to learn the intricacies of PHP coding. Still at baby steps.

I am trying to practice my PHP coding skills and started with trying to create a Marks aggregation system wherein school teachers can, visually get to know the ups and downs in student's performance, based on academic scores.

Scenario: Student's Marks are stored in MySQL table and the teacher needs to look at 30(assume) students' records. My thought is to show the marks by 'coloring the individual marks(foreground-only: the color of digits are to stand out for easier reference' based on a coloring system.

That is, for UT1(unit test 1), if a student has scored:

- Greater than 81, score should displayed in green color.
- Greater than 60 but below 80, score should displayed in orange color.

Simply put

- Marks >= 81 and <=100 should be green in color(100 marks is the benchmark)
- Marks >=61 and <=80 should be orange in color
- Marks >=41 and <=60 should be red in color

My code trials until now have come up to here:

```
<?php 

                        // color code function
                        function color_marks($marks) {

                                $color_code = "";

                                // echo "Marks: " .$marks;

                                /* if($marks>=0 && $marks<=40) { return $color_code = "FF0000";} 
                                elseif($marks>=41 && $marks<=60) { return $color_code = "FF4444";}
                                elseif($marks>=61 && $marks<=80) { return $color_code = "FF8800";} 
                                elseif($marks>=81 && $marks<=100) { return $color_code = "00FF00";} 
                                */

                                if ($marks >= 81) { 
                                    $color_code = "00FF00";
                                    echo "<br />Returning color:".$color_code;
                                    return $color_code = "00FF00";
                                }
                                elseif ($marks >= 61) {
                                    return $color_code = "FF8800";
                                }
                                elseif ($marks >= 41) {
                                    return $color_code = "FF4444";
                                }
                                else {
                                    return $color_code = "FF0000";
                                }

                                echo "<br />Returning color:".$color_code;
                            //if($marks<=60) { return $color_code = "GREEN";} else return $color_code = "RED";

                                /* if($marks>=81 && $marks<=100) { return $color_code = "338800";} 
                                else { if($marks>=61 && $marks<=80) { return $color_code = "FF8800";} 
                                else { if($marks>=41 && $marks<=60) { return $color_code = "FF4444";}
                                else { if($marks>=0 && $marks<=40) { return $color_code = "FF0000";}
                                } }} */


                        }

                        // START DEFAULT DATATABLE 
                        echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
                            echo "<div class='panel-heading'>";                                
                                echo "<h3 class='panel-title'>Marks of X<sup>th</sup> A - Section</h3>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<div class=panel-body'>";
                                echo "<table class='table datatable'>";
                                    echo "<thead>";
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<th style='text-align:center;'>Roll No.</th>";
                                            echo "<th>Student Name</th>";
                                            echo "<th style='text-align:center;'>Unit 1</th>";
                                            echo "<th style='text-align:center;'>Unit 2</th>";
                                            echo "<th style='text-align:center;'>Quarterly</th>";
                                            echo "<th style='text-align:center;'>Unit 3</th>";
                                            echo "<th style='text-align:center;'>Half-Yearly</th>";
                                            echo "<th style='text-align:center;'>Unit 4</th>";
                                            echo "<th style='text-align:center;'>Annually</th>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                    echo "</thead>";

                                    echo "<tbody>";

                                // Get data from the table from here
                                include('../config.inc.php');

                                $sql_query="SELECT * FROM learn_php.2015_2016_test_marks";
                                $result = mysqli_query($connecDB, $sql_query);

                                $color_code = '';


                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                                    echo " ut1_marks - ".color_marks($row['ut1_marks'])." - ".$row['ut1_marks'];
                                    echo " ut2_marks - ".color_marks($row['ut2_marks'])." - ".$row['ut2_marks'];
                                    // lets find what color the marks are
                                    if ($row['ut1_marks'] >0 ) { $color_code = color_marks($row['ut1_marks']); } 
                                    if ($row['ut2_marks'] >=0 ) { $color_code = color_marks($row['ut2_marks']); }
                                    /*
                                    if ($row['quarterly_marks'] >=0 ) { $color_code = color_marks($row['quarterly_marks']); }
                                    if ($row['ut3_marks'] >=0 ) { $color_code = color_marks($row['ut3_marks']); }
                                    if ($row['half_yearly_marks'] >=0 ) { $color_code = color_marks($row['half_yearly_marks']); }
                                    if ($row['ut4_marks'] >=0 ) { $color_code = color_marks($row['ut4_marks']); }
                                    if ($row['annual_marks'] >=0 ) { $color_code = color_marks($row['annual_marks']); }
                                    */


                                    // echo "<font color='#".$color_code."'>". $row['ut1_marks'] . "</font>";
                                    // Ok, got the color codes - lets show the magic in the table
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . $row['student_uid'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['student_name'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . "<font color='#".$color_code."'>". $row['ut1_marks'] . "</font>"."</td>";

                                        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . "<font color='#".$color_code."'>". $row['ut2_marks'] . "</font>"."</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . "<font color='#".$color_code."'>". $row['quarterly_marks'] . "</font>"."</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . "<font color='#".$color_code."'>". $row['ut3_marks'] . "</font>"."</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . "<font color='#".$color_code."'>". $row['half_yearly_marks'] . "</font>"."</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . "<font color='#".$color_code."'>". $row['ut4_marks'] . "</font>"."</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . "<font color='#".$color_code."'>". $row['annual_marks'] . "</font>"."</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";   
                                }
                                echo "</table>";
                        ?>
```

Present scenario: Every field value is taking the color-input from the function. But, the color_code value is turning out be constant.

I've been trying to crack this for the past few days, but unable to do so.

Please, if someone can give me a second thought on what I had done wrong, that would be an enormous leap.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: You say that your function always returns the same value - which one? Are you passing the right values into your function? Have you checked the data that you're retrieving from the database is correct?

Comment: First of all I don't thing this should be handled in PHP. It's work for a presentation layer. Second thing `<font></font>` HTML tag is deprecated and you should use CSS instead. Can you post your output? I have tried you `color_marks()` function and it worked as you suppose.

Comment: Echoed the data coming from the db and checked on 1 to 3 students to trace the reason, but failed to do so, Andrewsi.

Comment: Ohh, didn't realize that <font> tag is deprecated Lukas. Just learned that <label> is an alternate way to do that. I will use that going forward.